# Access object property via dot notation

Tags: javascript

I'm iterating over a collection returned from server; it looks like this:

```
roster: Array
    0: Object
        avatar: null
        contactName: "me@test.com"
        contactType: "grouping"
        displayName: "Joe Shmoe"
```

I'm creating a table and trying to add the "displayName" to it but accessing by dot notation isn't working. What is wrong with my code below?

```
function createAddressBook()
            {
                var tbl = document.getElementById( 'addressBook_tbl' );

                var tbdy = document.createElement( 'tbody' );

                // cells creation
                for( var j = 0; j <= roster.length; j++ ) 
                {
                    // table row creation
                    var row = document.createElement( "tr" );

                    for( var i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) 
                    {
                        // create element <td> and text node 
                        //Make text node the contents of <td> element
                        // put <td> at end of the table row
                        var cell = document.createElement( "td" );    
                        var cellText = document.createTextNode( roster[ j ].displayName ); 

                        cell.appendChild( cellText );
                        row.appendChild( cell );
                    }

                    //row added to end of table body
                    tbdy.appendChild( row );
                }

                // append the <tbody> inside the <table>
                tbl.appendChild( tbdy );
            }
```

Comment: and i bet that it is not working with square bracket notation also since you are not using `i` to access it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `j`, when you defined `i`.

```
// ----------------v-------should be `i`
"user: " + roster[ j ].displayName
```

---

FYI, you can use `.insertCell(-1)` to append a new cell.

```
row.insertCell(-1)
   .appendChild(document.createTextNode( "user: " + roster[ j ].displayName ));
```

---

***EDIT:*** While your updated code works, it does have one error.

You're trying to access `roster` at an index beyond its last index. Because Array indices are 0-based, the last index is `roster.length - 1`, so you should use `<` instead of `<=`.

```
// ---------------v
for( var j = 0; j < roster.length; j++ )
```

Comment: sorry, just updated my original post because it didn't show the outer loop with "J" defined.

Comment: Then your code works just fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/H2C8n/

Comment: @fumeng: There's one error in your code that won't manifest itself until the end of the `roster` loop. I updated my answer.

Comment: As soon as I fixed the <= issue you mentioned, my data is showing just fine. Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: @fumeng: You're welcome. I assume the `tbdy` must have not been in the DOM during the loop.

Comment: True. I updated the post to show the entire method now.

Comment: @fumeng: Looks good. I'm just going to update your question to add the `<=` back in so that the answer makes sense.